# How to import .ldtk map for platformer game in rust & how to set collision for it?

Tags: rust, game-development, bevy

I've just started making this project, so there is nothing much in it.
I will use the bevy_ecs_ldtk dependency. [I will use any one of these .ldtk file](https://github.com/Trouv/bevy_ecs_ldtk/tree/main/assets)
I was also looking for collision setup, is there a automatic way to do it, while using ldtk?

main.rs:

```rust
use bevy::{prelude::*, window::PrimaryWindow};
use bevy_ecs_ldtk::prelude::*;

mod components;
mod systems;

const PLAYER_SPEED: f32 = 200.0;
const PLAYER_SIZE: f32 = 24.0;

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .insert_resource(ClearColor(Color::rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.9)))
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins.set(ImagePlugin::default_nearest()))
        .add_systems(Startup, setup)
        .add_systems(Startup, systems::spawn_player)
        .add_systems(
            Update,
            systems::player_movement.before(systems::confine_player_movement),
        )
        .add_systems(Update, systems::confine_player_movement)
        .run();
}

fn setup(mut commands: Commands, asset_server: Res<AssetServer>) {
    commands.spawn(Camera2dBundle::default());

    let ldtk_handle = asset_server.load("Typical_2D_platformer_example.ldtk");
    commands.spawn(LdtkWorldBundle {
        ldtk_handle,
        ..default()
    });
}
```

systems.rs:

```rust
use bevy::{prelude::*, window::PrimaryWindow};

use crate::components::*;
use crate::*;

pub fn spawn_player(
    mut commands: Commands,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
    mut texture_atlases: ResMut<Assets<TextureAtlas>>,
) {
    let texture_handle = asset_server.load("gabe-idle-run.png");

    let texture_atlas =
        TextureAtlas::from_grid(texture_handle, Vec2::new(24.0, 24.0), 7, 1, None, None);
    let texture_atlas_handle = texture_atlases.add(texture_atlas);
    // Use only the subset of sprites in the sheet that make up the running animation
    commands.spawn((
        SpriteSheetBundle {
            texture_atlas: texture_atlas_handle,
            sprite: TextureAtlasSprite::new(1),
            transform: Transform {
                scale: Vec3::new(3.0, 3.0, 0.0),
                ..default()
            },
            ..default()
        },
        Player,
    ));
}

pub fn player_movement(
    keyboard_input: Res<Input<KeyCode>>,
    mut player_query: Query<&mut Transform, With<Player>>,
    time: Res<Time>,
) {
    if let Ok(mut transform) = player_query.get_single_mut() {
        let mut direction = Vec3::ZERO;

        if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::Left) || keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::A) {
            direction += Vec3::new(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }
        if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::Right) || keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::D) {
            direction += Vec3::new(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }

        if direction.length() > 0.0 {
            direction = direction.normalize();
        }

        transform.translation += direction * PLAYER_SPEED * time.delta_seconds();
    }
}

pub fn confine_player_movement(
    mut player_query: Query<&mut Transform, With<Player>>,
    window_query: Query<&Window, With<PrimaryWindow>>,
) {
    if let Ok(mut player_transform) = player_query.get_single_mut() {
        let window = window_query.get_single().unwrap();

        let half_player_size = PLAYER_SIZE;
        let x_min = -window.width() / 2.0 + half_player_size - 2.8;
        let x_max = window.width() / 2.0 - half_player_size;

        let mut translation = player_transform.translation;

        // Bound the player X position
        if translation.x < x_min {
            translation.x = x_min
        } else if translation.x > x_max {
            translation.x = x_max
        }

        player_transform.translation = translation;
    }
}
```

components.rs:

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;

#[derive(Component)]
pub struct Player;

#[derive(Clone, Default, Component)]
pub struct GroundDetection {
    on_ground: bool,
}
```

I've tried looking at their platformer example (which is what I'm trying to make)
but I didn't understand it.